# Apache create index for directories without one specified.

Tags: php, apache

Currently, I use a PHP script to list the contents of a directory that does not have an index file, but I don't want to have to copy it to *every* directory without an index.

Can Apache do it automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for, is `mod_autoindex`

```
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html
```

Make sure you have it enabled in the Apache configuration:

```
LoadModule autoindex_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_autoindex.so
```

Note: you may have to change the path directory to the module, or even change the module name. On SOME Apache servers I've seen, it may be just:

```
LoadModule mod_autoindex /path/to/mod.so
```

In response to the comments: (**edit**)

```
#put this in a `.htaccess` in your root directory
#this sends 403 errors to any directory w/o index.
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /path/to/file.php
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is really the one im looking for? Cuase im not able to find how exactly i will load the php file i created if there is no index file in the current directory.

Comment: @AKLP - If you are trying to list all the files in the directory that HAS NO INDEX then Apache does that automatically with that module. If you want to load "the PHP file" automatically, it just has to be called `index.php` but what does the PHP file do, list the directory contents? If so, delete the PHP file and use the `mod_autoindex`.

Comment: What i want to do is load the php file, but not for a single one but all directories without an index file.

Comment: @AKLP - Ok, this is totally unorthodox, but here's a way maybe to do that. You need to specify a custom error page and then use my `edits` in my answer above to put in the Apache config. Note: the downside to this, is that if you need a "real" 403 error, it's not possible. Apache will send the PHP file you have ANY time a 403 is sent.

Comment: Yes cool, that works. I want this feature mostly for localhost/dev work so i dont mind missing the 403 error

thanks!

Comment: Btw for some reason the ^/+$ is not targeting anything else except the root

Comment: @AKLP - See my revisions in my answer.